# Transpose a jagged array in C?

Tags: c, jagged-arrays

I've been having a problem transposing a jagged array in C for a few days now and I really can't find the solution. Basically we are given a matrix of mostly zeroes (sparse matrix) and we are meant to convert that to a jagged array. I'm able to do that no problem. The spare matrix is

```
7 8
0 0 0 5 1 0 0 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 5 0 0 3 0
1 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

With 7 and 8 being the rows and columns, which we are meant to read in first. Any point where the row is all zeroes (in this case, the second row), the jagged array is meant to have NULL. We are supposed to allocate memory for the jagged array using calloc() which I do inside of this loop:

```
for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<columns; j++)
    {
        if(matrix[i][j] != 0)
        {
            flag++;
        }
    }
    if(flag > 0)
    {
        jagged[i] = (float *)calloc(flag, sizeof(float));
    }
    else
    {
        jagged[i] = NULL;
    }
    flag = 0;
}
```

So my jagged array is printed as:

```
5 1 5
NULL
1 2
1
3 5 3
1 3
1
```

And this is printed as it is meant to be, and it works fine. We are then meant to add the jagged array to itself, which I do in this loop (inside a function):

```
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        if(jagged[i]) //if the row exists, continue
        {
            for(j=0; j<columns; j++)
            {
                if(jagged[i][j]) //if the index exists, add it to itself
                {
                    jagged[i][j] += jagged[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This also works fine, and the new jagged array is printed as:

```
10 2 10
2 4
2
6 10 6
2 6
2
```

The last part is where I am stuck. I am now meant to transpose the above array (rows become the columns). And I have tried several ways of going about this. I tried creating a new array using calloc() with a loop similar to the one above but looping through the jagged array, and with rows and columns reversed. However whenever I try to go down the column of the jagged array (loop starting at jagged[0][0] and then next iteration be at jagged[1][0]) I always get a segmentation fault, even though I'm checking if the next row/element being check is NULL. Is there any better way to do this transposition or am I making mistakes in the way I'm doing it that can be fixed? This has been frustrating me for almost a week now so any help is greatly appreciated. Further details can be provided if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you write `5 1 5` for the first row of the jagged array, does that represent the row `0 0 0 5 1 0 0 5` or the row `5 1 5 0 0 0 0 0` in the "full" array? How can we tell?

Comment: The matrix I gave is a .txt file we read in from, sorry I didn't mention that

Comment: The format of the input is not in question. The matrix row `5 1 5 0 0 0 0 0` is not the same as `0 0 0 5 1 0 0 5`. We can easily see which of these rows is in the _input_, the question is how can we know which of these two rows you have _stored_ in your jagged array.

Comment: I only read in non-zeroes into the array. The jagged array itself does not contain any zeroes.

Comment: Then you have lost essential information from the input. You cannot construct the transpose of the original input array from your data structure. It's also unclear what it would mean to "transpose" the data structure, since your data structure does not support matrix transposition.

Comment: The transposed jagged array should in the end look like this

    10 2 2 6 2 2(end of row)
    2 4 10 6(end of row)
    10 6(end of array)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. Your code removes all the `0` from the matrix but that is not what is being asked.  You can use `NULL` instead of allocating memory for a row that consists of entirely zeroes, but you cannot strip some `0`'s from within a line that has other numbers. When you output the matrix it should look just like it does in the file. (don't output NULL ; output `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the original input matrix is completely irrelevant to your question and is a red herring. I will ignore it and look only at your jagged arrays.

In order for the jagged array to be useful at all, you must have some way to know how many numbers are in each row. Otherwise you can never know whether you should read one more number from the row or whether that will result in a segfault.

Now suppose you have a way to know the number of numbers in each row, and you have stored a jagged array `m` like this:

```
10 2 10
2 4
2
6 10 6
2 6
2
```

Start with an empty jagged array `m_transpose`. Fundamentally what you want to do is,
for each row of `m`, for `i` counting upward from 0, 
read `x` from element `i` of that row of `m`; 
then find the first row of `m_transpose` that does not have `i+1` numbers in it already, 
and append `x` to that row of `m_transpose`.

If you must allocate exactly the right size array of `float` for each row of
`m_transpose`, then you will have to do this in two passes.
In the first pass you start with an array of zeros as long as the longest row of `m`,
and you iterate over each row of `m` as I already described except that 
instead of appending element `i` from a row of `m` to a row of `m_transpose`,
you just add 1 to the first element in your array of integers that is less than `i+1`.
Then you can allocate all the rows of `m_transpose` to the correct size,
and on the second pass you can copy the elements of `m` to `m_transpose`
as already described.
(Note that again you need an array of integers to keep track of where in each row
of `m_transpose` you should "append" the next number.)

Personally, unless the product of the length of the longest line of the jagged array and the number of non-empty lines of the array is *very* large (and much larger than the total number of non-zero elements of the array), I would allocate rectangular data structures
with a zero after the last non-zero number in every row.
You can then traverse the arrays safely without needing some auxiliary data structure
to tell you how long each row is.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the next element for NULL is not the solution. You have to stop iterating down a row before it runs out. As soon as you read jagged[i][j] where j is outside the bounds of that array you have segfault potential.

You would probably have a much easier time if you transposed first while the array is still rectangular and then made it jagged.

If that is not allowed you are going to have to keep track of how many items are in each row of the jagged array and set your limit for the j inner loop accordingly.

Comment: Even if I do something like this :

for(i=0; i<1; i++)
if(jagged[i]
for(j=0; j<2; j++)
if(jagged[j][i])
transposed[i][j] = jagged[j][i];

I still get a seg fault, even though I'm surely not out-stepping any bounds. Apologies for no formatting =/ but basically it only loops once outside and twice inside so it should check jagged[0][0] and jagged[1][0] but it seg faults anyway.

Comment: Also transposing first like you said is sadly not allowed.